# Fixed Button Heights on sides of a DIV

Tags: html, css

I can't figure this out. I need 2 buttons to stick... even with scrolling. The site uses Bootstrap. I have the buttons positioned where I want in Desktop and Mobile view. But I can't get them to stay fixed on side of the DIV. Suggestions please:

```html
<div class="span12">
  <asp:Panel>
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div style="width:100%; position: relative;">
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkP"><span style="width:14px; height:60px; position: absolute; top: 65px; left:-4px; text-align: center;"><i class="icon-chevron-left" style="position:relative; top:45%; transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-45%);"></i></span></asp:HyperLink>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkN"><span style="width:14px; height:60px; position: absolute; top: 65px; right:-4px; text-align: center;"><i class="icon-chevron-right" style="position:relative; top:45%; transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-45%);"></i></span></asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Table -->
    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>
            The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
            ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
            laborum."
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Maybe I am search using the wrong words.

Comment: Hi @7huan please include a screenshot of what it looks like.

Comment: position:fixed, r position:sticky instead of position:absolute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: do you want your buttons to be under the content? and why do you have them in the html before the copy (table)?

Comment: Hi all, I want them to be semi-permanent carousel buttons. That adjust with Bootstrap. Meaning I can't simply "position:fixed" them from what I have tried. The DIV being shown is the main center one. The side DIVs are hidden in mobile view. Sorry, no screenshots.

Comment: @CarolMcKay, thanks for that. position: sticky, is what i am looking for i think. NEW! supported by all browsers? let me try, will report back. thank you.

Comment: Avoid using on thead th or tr https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Carol's suggestion, **position:sticky**, I was able to get my desired layout with:

```
<div style="position: sticky; top:100px;">
    <div style="width:100%; position: relative;">
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkP"><span style="width:14px; height:60px; position: absolute; left:-8px; text-align: center;"><i class="icon-chevron-left" style="position:relative; top:45%; transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-45%);"></i></span></asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkN"><span style="width:14px; height:60px; position: absolute; right:-8px; text-align: center;"><i class="icon-chevron-right" style="position:relative; top:45%; transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-45%);"></i></span></asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I made an extra DIV and made it stick first.

Comment: Update: Works for my needs, but position:sticky is not working on Safari.